# SQL Query to get Distinct Values of all column values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

How to retrieve distinct values from all columns in a Table.

`Select Distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1` will give the unique records by checking the equality of all the columns. But I need all disctinct values from a table? Thanks in advance.

For Ex: My table has below records:

```
Col1                  Col2                  Col3                    Col4
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Melbourne             Sit1                  10.0                    5.3 
Melbourne             Sit2                  10.1                    5.4 
Sydney                Sit1                  10.0                    5.3 
Sydney                Sit3                  10.0                    5.3 
Bangalore             Sit1                  10.5                    0.1
```

The end result should be like below:

```
Result
----------------
Melbourne
Sydney
Bangalore
Sit1
Sit2
Sit3
10.0
10.1
10.5
5.3
5.4
5.1
```

Order doesn't matter.

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: I have provided the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select col1 from table union
select col2 from table union
. . .
select coln from table;
```

The use of `union` removes duplicate values.  Note that this assumes that the column types are compatible (such as all being strings).

EDIT:

If the column in a table has to have only one type.  (Okay, it *could* be a variant, but that is probably not a simplification.)  You can cast everything to `varchar2()`:

```
select cast(col1 as varchar2(255)) from table union
select cast(col2 as varchar2(255)) from table union
. . .
select cast(coln as varchar2(255)) from table;
```

Alternatively, you could group the columns by data type and do a separate run for each one, or a separate column for each data type.  It is unlikely that you will have exact matches across data types, so this might meet your need.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The Answer is somewhat in similar lines. But the column types are not compatible here, as you can see the edited question.