# Selecting Distinct Column Values in Database Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to find all the distinct values from all the columns in my DB table in Oracle DB.
I have tried doing a distinct on all the columns and it gives me the distinct combinations of all values and not the distinct value per column. Is there a better way to do this other than individually doing a distinct operation per column.
For Example:
Table Structure:
Indicator_Name Dimension1 Dimension2 ..... DimensionN

I need to find distinct values  per each dimension column

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds ominous and may indicate a serious design flaw. What are those columns meant to store? Why isn't it just one column? [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. And tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893637/sql-query-to-get-distinct-values-of-all-column-values-in-a-table

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the values into a single column.  Assuming that the data types are all compatible, then `union` does what you want:

```
select col1 from t
union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select col2 from t
union 
select col3 from t
union 
. . . ;
```

You can also use a lateral join:

```
select x.col
from t cross join lateral
     (select t.col1 from dual union all
      select t.col2 from dual union all
      . . .
     ) x;
```